# Control Cursor Movement for Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, cursor

I'm trying to create a sheet that can be shared live, data will be entered via a scanning of 2 qr codes so when the first code is scanned I need the cursor to move to the right to the next column and when data is scanned into A2 the cursor moves to B2 once data is scanned into B2 I need the cursor to move to A3 and so on.

Sample of Grid with movements needed:
[image: Sample of Grid with movements needed]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please checkout [ask].